# Probabilities Question independent events

Tags: probability, independence

There is a question as below :
An insurance company pays hospital claims. The number of claims that include emergency room or operating room charges is 85% of the total number of claims. The number of claims that do not include emergency room charges is 25% of the total number of claims. The occurrence of emergency room charges is independent of the occurrence of operating room charges on hospital claims.
Calculate the probability that a claim submitted to the insurance company
consists only of operating room charges.

Let operation room be $O$ and emergency be $E$.

$P(O) = 0.40$, which is the answer.

The question is doesn't the phrase "consists only of operating room charges" mean $P(O)-P(O)\cdot P(E)$?  Why then say that $Pr(O)$ is the answer?

Comment: Please check the first sentence in your second paragraph.

Comment: i was about to answer with, but i couldn't find the union and intersection signs, so just wrote the answer and forgot to remove that sentences , thanks

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  As you point out, $P(O)$ is the probability that any bill includes operating room charges, while $P(O) - P(O \cap E) = P(O) - P(O)P(E)$ is the probability that a bill includes only operating room charges.

Comment: I agree with the above comment -- I think your book is wrong, because they were using unclear notation which confused them.